# How to properly generate a long stream where one number should be skipped?

Tags: optimization, java-stream

The method should return long stream from -n to n except 0. For n = 3 the stream should be -3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3.

What approach is better?

(1)

```java
public static LongStream getLongStream(int n) {
    return n == 0 
        ? LongStream.empty() 
        : LongStream.concat(
            LongStream.range(-n, 0), 
            LongStream.rangeClosed(1, n));

}
```

(2)

```java
public static LongStream getLongStream(int n) {
    return LongStream.concat(
            LongStream.range(-n, 0), 
            LongStream.rangeClosed(1, n));

}
```

Thank you for your comments.
I suppose that the second variant is the best way to produce such streams.

Comment: It’s a matter of taste. My taste is for the shorter version. Some would find it cryptic and prefer the longer, more explicit one.

Comment: I don’t see different approaches. Both methods use the same approach, but one contains an optimization for the `n == 0` case, which obviously will only be worthwhile when the method is invoked with zero often enough. Since it rather looks like a corner case for this method, I’d expect the opposite, the method being rarely invoked with zero, hence, not benefitting from the optimization.

Answer (score 2):

It will be a matter of taste. Take the version that you and in particular your readers — those maintaining your code after you — will prefer. Here’s yet an option. I like to make your requirement *one number should be skipped* more explicit in the code.

```
public static LongStream getLongStream(int n) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(-n, n).filter(i -> i != 0);
}
```

To try it out:

```
    System.out.println(getLongStream(3).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Output:

> [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]

It’s less runtime efficient than your versions. Holger’s comment seems to indicate that the difference may be great for large values of `n`, though depending on what you are using the stream for. If concerned, you will need to make your own measurements.

Comment: The disadvantage is that now every element is tested against zero which can be a lot of tests when the `LongStream` turns out to be a long stream (though the `n` parameter is an `int` which begs the question why the method doesn’t produce an `IntStream`). Since this also destroys the information about the number of result elements, operations like `toArray` become less efficient.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the comment. I had not noticed the [tag:optimization] tag at first. But also there’s no indication in the question as to whether readability, space consumption, speed or something else should be optimized. You may not think that I have answered the question as intended. I have undeleted the answer for now, ready to think again.

Comment: There’s nothing wrong with presenting alternatives, when the pros and cons are included.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in terms of optimization the second variant is the best one.

```
public static LongStream getLongStream(long n) {
    return LongStream.concat(
            LongStream.range(-n, 0), 
            LongStream.rangeClosed(1, n));

}
```